# Matplotlib not setting minimum y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is probably a simple question, but setting the bottom y=axis simply isn't working. I believe it is occurring as a result of me using the area chart, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here is my current code.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig.suptitle('SPY Chart')
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=150, top=450)
spyData['Close'].plot(kind='area',ax=ax1)
spyData['Close'].plot(ax=ax2)
```

Changing the value of the top works perfectly well, but the bottom won't.

Comment: with `sharey=True` the y-axes of both plots are shared. Changing one will automatically change the other one.  If this isn't what you want, you can set `sharey=False` (the default).

Comment: @JohanC I would like it to be shared, but for 150 to be the bottom for both. Is this possible with sharey enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot commands called after setting the `ylim`s changes these limits again.  Calling `set_ylim()` *after* the plot commands solves this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

spyData = pd.DataFrame({'Close': np.random.normal(0.1, 10, 200).cumsum() + 200})
spyData.set_index(pd.date_range('20200101', periods=len(spyData)), inplace=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
spyData['Close'].plot(kind='area', ax=ax1)
spyData['Close'].plot(ax=ax2)
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=150, top=450)
ax1.margins(x=0) # suppress white space left and right
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]